# Find the value of $\underset{0\leq i \lt j\leq n}\sum{\binom{n}{i}}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

My approach:

$$\underset{0\leq i \lt j\leq n}\sum{\binom{n}{i}}=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}=\sum_{j=0}^n2^n=2^n(n+1).$$

But the answer is actually $n2^{n-1}$. Am I doing the double sum wrong?

EDIT:

I messed up the indices in the double sum.
Following @5xum's answer we have,
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}{n\choose i}=\sum_{j=0}^n\bigg[\binom{n}{0}+\biggl[\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\biggr]+\biggl[\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}\biggr]+\cdots$$
$$=\sum_{r=0}^n(n-r)\binom{n}{r}=n2^{n-1}$$
Is this the correct way to do it or is there any other way?

Comment: The sum's limit is $1$ in the title, but $0$ in the body. Which is it? This will affect the final answer!

Comment: For future reference: write entire mathematical expressions, not just individual symbols, in math mode. In other words, write `$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + 10$` (which yields "$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} + 10$") instead of `f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$ + 10` which yields a much uglier "f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$ + 10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i$ must be smaller than $j$, and neither of which is the condition missing when you write out the double sum.

So it should be

$$\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}{n\choose i} = \sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}{n\choose i}$$

Comment: Oh my bad....but how do you proceed?

Comment: @ParthShresth I suggest you try to proceed first, tell us how far you got, and if you are still stuck, I can help out some more! Trust me, trying it out for your self is a much much much better way of learning than just having the result spelled out for you.

Comment: I updated the answer... have a look!

Comment: @ParthShresth How do you know that $$\sum_{j=0}^n(n-r)\binom{n}{r}=n2^{n-1}?$$ Where does this equality come from?

Comment: $$\sum_{r=0}^n(n-r)\binom{n}{r}=n\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}-\sum_{r=0}^n r\binom{n}{r}=n2^n-n2^{n-1}=n2^{n-1}$$

Comment: @ParthShresth Looks good, as long as you can justify why $\sum_{r=0}^n{n\choose r} = 2^n$ and why $\sum_{r=0}^n r{n\choose r} = n2^{n-1}$. You probably already solved those two in class or in a textbook, right?

Comment: Yeah, these are some standard results from my high school binomial theorem class

Comment: @ParthShresth In that case, you are done :) . Don't forget to accept one of the two answers you received.

Answer (score 2):

Your first equality is wrong: you should be summing over $0\leq i<j\leq n$, not $0\leq i,j\leq n$.

$$
\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n} \binom{n}{i}
= \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n \binom{n}{i}
$$

Comment: The inner sum should be $i$ from $0$ to $j-1$, actually.

Comment: @5xum Urgh, thanks. Too late for me... I had swapped i and j.

Comment: The $i$ should be from $0$ to $n-1$ shouldn’t it

Comment: No, that works. For $i=n$, the inner sum has zero terms, so it's OK.